# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 5

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I can't get the data from my form to load into MySQL Database. Please help!
This is the error that i get:

> Error: INSERT INTO add_review (name,email,details) VALUES ( 'Darron
>   Brown', 'blank@gmail.com', 'ldldjd', ) You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 5

```
<?php
// Connect to MySQL
  // a. Variables
  $host = "hostname";
  $username = "user";
  $password = "secretpassword";
  $dbname = "myDatabase";

  // b. Connection
  $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

  // c. Check our connection
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " .
      mysqli_connect_error() .
      " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );
  }
  // Insert our data
  $name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : "";
  $email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "";
  $details = isset($_POST["details"]) ? $_POST["details"] : "";

  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $name);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $email);
  $details = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $details);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO add_review (name,email,details) VALUES (
          '$name',
          '$email',
          '$details',
        )";
// $insert = $connection->query($sql);

  // Print response from MySQL
  if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}

  // Close our connection
  mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

```html
<div class = "section page">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <h1>Add a Review</h1>
    <p>If you think there is something I am missing, let me know! Complete the form to send me an email.</p>
    <form method="post" action="">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th><label for="name">Movie Name</label></th>
          <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th><label for="email">Email</label></th>
          <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th><label for="email">Suggest Movie Details</label></th>
          <td><textarea name="details" id="details"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `'$details',` ??? check comma, and its better to use prepared statement for preventing SQL attack

Comment: remove the comma after '$details' then learn mysqli prepared as @devpro have suggested above.

Comment: yup @MasivuyeCokile

Answer (score 1):

See the syntex for `'$details',` change your query and remove the extra comma after $details like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO add_review (name,email,details) VALUES (
          '$name',
          '$email',
          '$details'
        )";
```

**NB : You are at  risk of SQL Injections, Learn mysqli_prepared to prevent sql injections, you can learn [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)**

Your code with prepared statements would look like this :

```
<?php
// prepare and bind 
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO add_review (name,email, details) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$sql->bind_param("sss", $name, $email, $details);


$sql->execute();


echo "New records created successfully";

$sq]->close();
$conn->close();

?>
```

Now explaining the function :

```
$sql->bind_param("sss", $name, $email, $details);
```

This function binds the parameters to the SQL query and tells the database what the parameters are. The "sss" argument lists the types of data that the parameters are. The s character tells mysql that the parameter is a string.

The argument may be one of four types:

i - integer
d - double
s - string
b - BLOB
We must have one of these for each parameter.

By telling mysqli what type of data to expect, we minimize the risk of SQL injections.

> **Important : When you  insert any data from external sources (eg user**
>   **input from a form), it is very important that the data is sanitized and validated.**